# Installing Wordpress only with an public_html folder

Tags: wordpress

I have to move an already done Wordpress Website to another hosting, I got a dropbox with an public_html folder including these files

[image]

Am I able to rehost the Website only with this folder? I swapped my public_html server with the downloaded one, and I had to setup WordPress and only got the theme loaded, with the default Example Text things

Comment: You need the database also.  Then - PRO TIP: If the domain has changed, you'll need to run a db updae script to update the domain.  The script to use is this: https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/blob/master/srdb.class.php - Why? Because WP stores data in serialized data, and the URL is _everywhere_ in the DB, and if you don't use this script, it will break / corrupt the serialized data.

Comment: http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: hey, so apparently the website owner deleted *everything* except the public-html folder... Can I reconstruct some things with it or is it totally useless?

Comment: Oh boy.  Sorry about that! That makes life hard! I have reconstructed sites before utilizing the [waybackmachine](https://archive.org/web/) - visiting it, entering the URL of the site, and looking at the most recent archive of the site, you can often get a pretty good picture of what the site looked like.  And, they normally store multiple / all of the pages that are public-facing, so it's a good resource.

Comment: This is so depressing. The situation is like following: My relatives paid a dude making their website for 2 grant (for a Wordpress Website, without anything special, so rip off since beginning) then after the website is up for a year, he wants very high hosting bills, 300 Pounds, I repeat for an static wordpress website with like 10 hits a month.. Then they want their Website back, he doesnt give it to them, they sue him, he sends the public_html folder, deletes the website, and now hes being very unfriendly to me when I ask him where the rest of the website is.

Comment: Random idea: check the wp-content folder, look in "uploads".  Check for DB backups in there - some plugins will drop one into that folder.  Normally, either a  `.sql` or `.zip` extension on the file.

Comment: @cale_b only images in the folder

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-load your database too, for that you have to create a backup that includes the data and not only the structure of the database from the original server, you can use `phpMyAdmin` or the command line of mysql for that purpose.

After that, you have to execute that `*.sql` file in your new server to get your old posts, comments, etc..

Comment: I already thought so. Which folder is needed? I dont have access to the old files, so I have to guide the person through giving me the files

Comment: It's not a folder, it's a database, you have to use a command like `mysqldump` to extract your tables and the information stored in them, please refer to this link for further explanation: [How to Back Up Your WordPress Database](https://css-tricks.com/back-wordpress-database/). If you have no longer access to that server, then you have to ask the owner to generate a dump of your database, please keep in mind that he might need your MySQL password for that.

Comment: If you have access to _the old site_ (via the front-end), you can install and use a plugin like BackWPUp to get a DB dump easily.